# Web app in Streamlit with multiple questions per page

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm working on a web app in Streamlit and I am looking for a way to have multiple questions per page (see below). At the moment if a user replies to the first question *or* to the second one, the app automatically loads the next set of questions. How can I change things so that the next set of questions is loaded only if the user replies to both the first question *and* to the second one?

The logic I am using at the moment is the following:

```
st.table(Text_lines)
col1, col2 = st.columns([1,1])
with col3:
    if st.button('Option 1'):
        st.session_state.option1 = 1
with col4:
    if st.button('Option 2'):
        pass

st.table(Other_text_lines)
col3, col4 = st.columns([1,1])
with col3:
    if st.button('Sensible (Q)'):
        st.session_state.sensibility = 1
with col4:
    if st.button('Not sensible (W)'):
        pass
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to control the loading of questions by form. The user will press the submit button when done.

**Example**

```py
import streamlit as st


if 'num' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.num = 0


choices1 = ['no answer', 'manila', 'tokyo', 'bangkok']
choices2 = ['no answer', 'thailand', 'japan', 'philippines']

qs1 = [('What is the capital of Japan', choices1),
    ('What is the capital of Philippines', choices1),
    ('What is the capital of Thailand', choices1)]
qs2 = [('What country has the highest life expectancy?', choices2),
    ('What country has the highest population?', choices2),
    ('What country has the highest oil deposits?', choices2)]


def main():
    for _, _ in zip(qs1, qs2): 
        placeholder = st.empty()
        num = st.session_state.num
        with placeholder.form(key=str(num)):
            st.radio(qs1[num][0], key=num+1, options=qs1[num][1])
            st.radio(qs2[num][0], key=num+1, options=qs2[num][1])          
                      
            if st.form_submit_button():
                st.session_state.num += 1
                if st.session_state.num >= 3:
                    st.session_state.num = 0 
                placeholder.empty()
            else:
                st.stop()


main()
```

**Output**
[image]

Press submit and new set of questions will be loaded.
[image]